# I failed to get facebook recource page using this java code:

Tags: java, php, html, facebook

for a test i want to try get facebook recource page using that java code:
it is work for any other site but facebook\ twitter, any solutions?

```
public class ReadWebPage {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

String urltext = "http://www.facebook.com";
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
  URL url = new URL(urltext);
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

  String inputLine;
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (in != null) {
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What errors are returned? I suspect it has something to do with "http://www.facebook.com/" redirecting to "https://www.facebook.com". I suggest trying the https address and seeing if that corrects the problem.